# Access to the shell command prompt in NEO4J CE 3.0

Tags: neo4j

I am a "not familiar with programming" neo4j CE user. Nevertheless i used to create the database in NEO4J CE 2.3 by accessing to the command prompt via the options menu in NEO4J desktop interface, running the following command:
neo4jshell -file c:/users/bg/database/bg3_data/script.cql
where script.cql enable to create the database using multiple LOAD CSV commands.

Despite my research i did not find the way to do it with a similar method in neo4j 3.0.CE

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To use `neo4j-shell`, you have to download the TAR/ZIP distribution from: http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/

Or use a tool like: http://www.lyonwj.com/LazyWebCypher/

Or a different shell:

- [CyCli (Python)](https://github.com/nicolewhite/cycli)
- [libneo4j-client (C)](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was possible to access the Neo4j Shell by running CMD, then change directory to the Folder where Neo4j is installed

> cd "Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.0.4"

then run the command

> java -classpath bin\neo4j-desktop-3.0.4.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient

hope this helps.

Comment: I'm currently using Neo4J CE 3.2.6 now and tried the command : java -classpath bin\neo4j-desktop-3.2.6.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient with following error : Connection refused